# Facebook Dynamic Purchase Value

Tags: facebook

I need some help setting up the "dynamic" value for the facebook pixel. I'm not 100% familiar with Magento and these no datafeed to go off of. Here's the Facebook line I need to modify:

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency:'USD'});
```

Are either of the below the correct value to replace the '0.00'?

Value: `?php echo number_format($quote->getGrandTotal(),2,'.','');?`,

Value: `<?php echo $amount; ?>`,